# I need not to show this when one of the bundle products are out of stock

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, bundled-product, inventory, if

I have the following that shows a bundle of products on the product page:

```
if ($_product->getAttributeText('bundle') == yes && $simplecount > 1):
$product_ids = explode(',',$_product->get_bundle_products());

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $product_ids));

echo'<div class="bun2c" style="text-align:center; float:right;">';
foreach($collection as $eachproduct){
echo '<a href="' . $eachproduct->getProductUrl() . '"><img class="bundle" src="' . $eachproduct->getImageUrl() . '" title="' . $eachproduct->getName() . '"></a>';
$productId = $eachproduct->getId();
$simplecount = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($eachproduct)->getQty();
}
```

This works fine but I need not to show this when one of the bundle products are out of stock.

I have tried with item quatity($simplecount) but does not work.

Ive used `Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($eachproduct)->getIsInStock()` but this only works when every item is out of stock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get what I wanted and here is what I did,

First I calculated the items that were in stock:

```
$fullstock = 0;
$inStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($eachproduct)->getIsInStock();
$fullstock += $inStock;
```

I then got the product count of the bundle:

```
$product_count = count($collection);
```

I then used `$fullstock == $product_count` in my `if` statement

The complete code is as follows

```
$ids = array();
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$fullstock = 0;
    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $ids[$item->getProductId()] = $item->getProductId(); //used array key here to avoid duplicates
    }
$product_ids = explode(',',$_product->getbundle_products());
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $product_ids));
    foreach($collection as $eachproduct){
        $productId = $eachproduct->getId();
        $inStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($eachproduct)->getIsInStock();
        $fullstock += $inStock;
}
$product_count = count($collection);
    if ($_product->getAttributeText('bundle') == yes && $fullstock == $product_count):  
        echo'<div class="fgfgdfd" style="text-align:center; float:right;">';
    foreach($collection as $eachproduct){
        echo '<a href="' . $eachproduct->getProductUrl() . '"><img class="bundle" src="' . $eachproduct->getImageUrl() . '" title="' . $eachproduct->getName() . '"></a>';
            $productId = $eachproduct->getId();
if (isset($ids[$productId])) {
    echo '<span class="bundle-check">&#10003;</span>';
}
$combined_price += $eachproduct->getFinalPrice()/100*$_product->getbundle_discount();
}
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB.UTF-8');
echo '<div><p class="availability in-stock">Save <span class="in-stock1">' . money_format('%.2n', $combined_price) . '</span> <span class="when-you"> When you buy</span> <span class="with-with"> with</span> the bundle</p></div></div>';
endif;
```